# Type 'Location' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' -- MKAnnotation UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, mkannotation

I'm a French newbie in Swift programmation and I want to show annotations from a JSON file with UIKit (not swiftUI because I want to cluster my annotations). I create a class who are decodable and a MKAnnotation and I have an issue : "Type 'Location' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

Thanks you very much for yours answers !

Here my Location class

```
class Location: NSObject, Decodable, Identifiable, MKAnnotation {
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude : Double
    var coordinate:  CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    
    init(id : Int, name : String, latitude : Double, longitude : Double){
        
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
    }
    
}
```

And my JsonFile

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "New York City",
      "latitude": 40.71,
      "longitude": -74
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Barcelona",
      "latitude": 41.38,
      "longitude": 2.17
    }
```

Comment: In a `Codable` struct, each property needs to be `Codable`. Here `var coordinate:  CLLocationCoordinate2D` isn't `Codable`, hence your error. If you don't create it yourself, you could use a computed one: `var coordinate:  CLLocationCoordinate2D { CLLocationCoordinate(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) }`, and then it might not complain about trying to convert `location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `coordinate` a computed property

```
var coordinate:  CLLocationCoordinate2D{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}
```

or

```
var coordinate:  CLLocationCoordinate2D{
    get{
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
    set{
        latitude = newValue.latitude
        longitude = newValue.longitude
    }
}
```